# How to use transition animation of material design with android kitkat or lower

Tags: java, android, animation, android-4.4-kitkat, material-design

I develop a android app that will have min sdk 17. I wont to use a material design transition animation between activity like this project in github : https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations
My problem that is not turned my project in kitkat sdk or lower. I get this exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.transition.Explode
    at com.lgvalle.material_animations.MainActivity.setupWindowAnimations(MainActivity.java:36)
```

I wont to know if it is possible to use like throws animation ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say you can't. Activity Transitions need API level 21 or greater:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

You can always try to find a backport project to do them. But it's usually not a good idea since pre-lollipop devices are known for not rendering this kind of animations smoothly.